# How to clear all geofences and set up new ones based on user's location?

Tags: ios, swift, geofencing

Basically what I wold like to happen is when the user starts the app a "getNearbyLocations" is executed. This code is already in place.  Then we clear all existing fences and set up new ones for the nearest stores. That way, if the user approaches a store, the geofence kicks the app, and then we can use the lat/long to then check in. In the code I currently have the lat/long is hardcoded in:

```
   //Location info for check -in
    var latitude: CLLocationDegrees = 32.991652
    var longitude: CLLocationDegrees = -96.8511617
    var center: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    var radius: CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(10.0)
    var identifier: String = "storeID"
    var geoRegion: CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)

    geoRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    geoRegion.notifyOnExit = false


    // Core Location manager
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    manager.startMonitoringForRegion(geoRegion)
```

How to set it up so the geofence automatically clears and sets new ones up based on a users location?

Comment: Your question seems quite broad.  What are you actually asking?  How to determine the user's location?  How to determine a set of geofences nearest that location?  How to determine that the user has moved?  How to remove the current geofences and monitor a new set when they do move?

Comment: You might want to look at a service such as https://www.plotprojects.com/ or  campaign kit from https://www.radiusnetworks.com/

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
locationManager.monitoredRegions.forEach { region in
  if region is CLCircularRegion {
    locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region) // This line does the job
  }
}
```